# Understanding CNN training results

Tags: training-data, loss-function, conv-neural-network, sgd

I would appreciate your explanation on following :)

I trained CNN network that classifies TWO image classes.
I used 'SGD' optimizer and 'categorical_crossentropy' loss function.

My results are as follows:
- training loss = 0.28
- training accuracy = 0.93
- validation loss = 0.38
- validation accuracy = 0.82

So it is obvious the model 'overfits' a little (some people say little overfitting is sometimes good).

My question(s) are focused on **validation** loss and **validation** accuracy.

Is my network 38% inaccurate or 82% accurate?
I`ve read alot about **validation** loss and **validation** accuracy, and people say that:

'Unlike accuracy, loss is not a percentage. It is a summation of the errors made for each example in training or validation sets.'

But I still do not intuitively understand the results (38% inaccurate or 82% accurate).

Many thanks! :)

Ivan

Answer (score 0):

Your validation set (regarded as the best estimation of real-world performance) is 0.82 meaning it classifies the images correctly with 82% accuracy. The training loss is not a direct function of the accuracy.